# How to map a distance between 2 cities (relationship JPA)

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a question about JPA annotation.
I have 2 classes

```
@Entity(name="CITY")
@Table(name="CITY")
@SequenceGenerator(name="seqCITY", initialValue=0, allocationSize=1)
public class CITY{

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seqCITY")
    private int num;
    private String libelle;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Distance> listDistanceCity;
}
```

and

```
@Entity(name="DISTANCE")
@Table(name="DISTANCE")
public class Distance {

    @Id 
    private int num;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_city1")
    private City city1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_city2")
    private City city2;

    private float distance;

}
```

Are these annotation correct if I want to express a distance between 2 cities ? 
For example, from New York, there is distance with Manhattan, San francisco, Los Angeles. And a distance is composed of 2 cities.

There is a fixed set of cities in the database, there will not be any insert or update.

Comment: Yeah, looks correct to me, however, I did not understand why you need this table in first place.. is it distance by road?

Comment: Yes it is more or less by road. The important thing is to have a distance, because it is fixed in the database.
Thanks for your answer !

Comment: I have removed the UML tag, because this question does not have any reference to the Unified Modeling Language standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, this looks fine, but as I see, you will have a Composite key in the table, because same city combination should not repeat again. In such case, you can define  it in the model this way

```
@Entity
public class City {
    @Id
    private int num;
}
```

Create an Embeddable key, that can be used to enforce uniqueness

```
@Embeddable
public class CitySet implements Serializable {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_city1")
private City city1;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_city2")
private City city2;
}
```

Use the same key along with you Id in the final class

```
@Entity(name="DISTANCE")
@Table(name="DISTANCE")
@IdClass(CitySet.class)
public class Distance {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int num;

@Id
private City city1;

@Id
private City city2;

private float distance;

}
```

Hope this helps